# CocoaLumberjack.h file not found?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoalumberjack

Actually my project does compile for an iPhone 6s but not for any iOS simulators. When I want to build for a simulator I get two build time errors.
**Errors**

```
'CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h' file not found
```

and

```
failed to emit precompiled header 
'/DerivedData/Project/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Bridging-Header-swift.pch' 
for bridging header 
'/Users/Development/ProjectMobile/Views/Project-Bridging-Header.h'
```

**What have I tried yet?**

- `pod deintegrate`, clear Build, delete "DerivedData", `pod install` and `pod update`
- open `Project.xcworkspace` instead of `Project.xcodeproj`
- keep target iOS version in `podfile` and deployment target the same (iOS 12)
- check "Framework Search Paths" at targets build settings [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KsCal.png)
- check "Header Search paths" [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgrznl.png)

I am not 100% sure if the paths are correct. And I am wondering that Xcode can't find `Cocoalumberjack.h`, because I can find it under `/Pods/CocoaLumberjack/Sources/CocoaLumberjack/Supporting Files/CocoaLumberjack.h`.

**Questions**
Are these paths probably incorrect?
What else could be the problem?

I am happy for every serious answer!

(1) **Framework Search Paths**
[image: Framework Search Paths]

(2) **Header Search paths**
[image: Header Search paths]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode couldn't build the project for an iOS simulator because there was **no valid CPU architecture set for the simulator** (respectively for the Mac).

Under `Project > Targets > User-Defined > VALID_ARCHS` there were just `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64` architectures set.

I added `x86_64` architecture to the `VALID_ARCHS` and it works fine now.

Comment: According to Apple you should remove the VALID_ARCHS property completely (this action also fixes the issue you were experiencing)