# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue after upgrade to Xcode 12

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I got this issue after upgraded to Xcode 12

Lexical or Preprocessor Issue . File not found.

[image]

Not just CocoaLumberjack, it happens for ReactiveCocoa also, both are the newest version.

It works fine in Xcode 11

I'm using CocoaPods, the newest version.

Comment: How did you add them? CocoaPods? Carthage? Are they up to date? Because they might have fixed some issues. If I remember correctly, CocoaPods have fixed their issue, and Carthage was waiting for a solution...

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64245802/cocoalumberjack-h-file-not-found

Comment: @Larme I'm using CocoaPods, the newest version

Answer (score 0):

I Had the Same Error with 1.52.

Go to cocoapods.org and install Cocoapods version 1.10

1.52 looks Like The newest Version, But It Is 1.10.